# Use Case Statement Based on input Parameters in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have need to apply certain logic in one of our stored procedures.

We have a  parameter `@season` in the sp.

If  `@season`  = 0, then i have to entire years budget value.

if  `@season`  = 1, then i have to take tax-season budget values

if  `@season`  = 2, then i have to take pre-season budget values.

i derived startdate and enddate of each season
as `@SeasonStrt` , `@SeasonEnd`

`@SeasonStart` is from January 1 to April 30 and `@SeasonEnd` from May 1 to December 30

I have tried something like below,

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(lab.BudgetAmt,0)), 
SUM(ISNULL(lab.ProjectedHours,0))  
FROM [dbo].[Budget] bud

WHERE  [Year] = @taxyear
AND ((@season = 0) OR (Season= @season))
        AND CASE WHEN @season in (1,2)
         THEN bud.[week]   >= CASE WHEN @season in (1,2)THEN @SeasonStrt ELSE bud.[week] END
         AND bud.[week]    <= CASE WHEN @season in (1,2)THEN @SeasonStrt ELSE bud.[week] END
```

Sql server gives syntax error. What will be solution which meets my requirement?

thanks for the help

Comment: You need to be more precise in telling us what the 3 different calendars are as we don't know your business rules. Perhaps just give us samples of the start and end dates for each season? then we can help translate that into T-SQL

Comment: Please provide a schema and sample data, or even better a SQLFiddle.

Comment: CASE returns one value, that's because it is seeing in selects returning a column. The error is due SQL expects something like value = case ... You can rewrite the WHERE without case statement or change it to use case in the righ way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(lab.BudgetAmt,0)), 
SUM(ISNULL(lab.ProjectedHours,0))  
FROM [dbo].[Budget] bud
WHERE  [Year] = @taxyear
AND 
(
    ((@season = 0) AND (Season = @season))
    OR ((@season = 1) AND (bud.[week] >= @SeasonStrt))
    OR ((@season = 2) AND (bud.[week] <= @SeasonStrt))
)
```

So, idea is simple: combine your conditions with `OR` and specific `@season` value

Comment: thanks for the solution. but one more query. what if the table have no column season ?   can i write like this,  ((@Season=0) OR .....